# Vectorizing Slicing Numpy by Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, slice

```
a = np.array([[3,5,6 ,7,8 ,5,11,4 ,5,3 ,6 ,0,7,8 ,0,2 ,3,4 ,4 ,5 ,2 ,8 ,5],
           [2,3,61,5,33,5,41,44,2,12,35,7,2,30,2,23,3,44,45,25,84,51,2]])
a = np.transpose(a)
idx_arr = np.arange(a.shape[0])
a = np.column_stack((a,idx_arr))
a_sorted = a[a[:,0].argsort()]
unique, index, inverse, counts  = np.unique(a_sorted[:,0], return_counts=True, return_inverse= True,  return_index = True)
```

Need to get array/array to count in each block with equal number in a_sorted[:,0]:

1. sums in a_sorted[:,1]. For example, for block "0" it will be "9" (7+2), for "2" - 107, for "3" - 17, etc.
2. qty of numbers with conditions in a_sorted[:,1]. For example, if condition <10, then for block "0" it will be "2", for "2" - "0" (both numbers in this block >10: 84 and 23), for block "3" - "2" (three numbers:3 , 12, 2), etc.
3. numbers in a_sorted[:,2] with conditions.  For example, if condition <10, then for block "0" it will be "11" and "14", for "2" - "None" (both numbers in this block >10: 84 and 23), for block "3" - "16" and "0" (two numbers:3, 2), etc.

I tried to use

```
sums = np.zeros(len(unique), dtype=a[:,1].dtype)
np.add.at(sums,inverse,a_sorted[:,1]<10)
```

but this solution solve only task #1.

I can make some kind of adresses array

```
slices_array = np.column_stack((index[:-1],index[1:]-1))
```

but I dont know how to obtain blocks were start of slice is in 1-st column of array and end of slice in 2-nd column i.e. array of slices

I need a vectorized solution, capable to use in CuPy in future.
Thanks!

UPD. So the slice length is vary i can find maximum length by

```
 max(index[1:]-index[:-1])
```

and prepare an empty array to fill by indexes

Comment: What actual output are you expecting?

Comment: Indexing with many slices has been asked before.  If the slice lengths vary, there isn't much you can do speed things up, since you are creating arrays that vary in shape.  If the  slice lengths are all the same, then you can construct an advanced indexing array that selects all values.  `linspace` can be handy for that, but it's also easy to broadcast a couple of arrays against each other.

Comment: What actual output are you expecting? - in best case - numpy array with unique numbers in 1-st column, and with answers on question like above in other columns.

Comment: In fact slice length is vary. But if I get counts (answers) on my tasks above - its doesnt matter. Like in case with np.add.at.